# Get function name from instantiated function

Tags: javascript

How can I get the name of an **instantiated** JavaScript function from inside it without knowing its name?

The reason I need it is because I started to work with exceptions and I want to get the name of the exception later as a string without writing the name manually into the exception function itself, like in the examples in the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw

**Example:**

```
function MyException(message) {
    this.message = message;
    this.name = 'MyException';  // How to get function name automatically?
    this.toString = function() {
        return this.name + ': ' + this.message;
    };
}

try {
    throw new MyException('Hello world');
}
catch (e) {
    alert(e);  // "MyException: Hello world"
}
```

There is `Function.name`, but it is not available as soon as a function is instantiated (through the `new` operator), because the function then becomes an object without any attributes or methods.

Comment: you can polyfill the .name for IE9+ with a getter that splits the toString(), or just log the toString()

Comment: I don't understand. How? There is no `name` attribute and the `toString()` method returns just `[object Object]`, since MyException is not a function anymore at that time (it is previously converted to an object through the `new` operator). Can you give an example of what you mean, please?

Comment: you can use the `constructor` property of an instance to get to the function...

Comment: Hmm... yes. This would circumvent the issue with strict mode for `callee`. It is an additional solution but I prefer to write the extraction code only once (with inheritance) and not for all exceptions again and again. Otherwise, one would need to modify every single exception function if something changes. But you are right - I didn't though about the constructor property. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Functions offer the `arguments` object with the `callee` attribute inside them, which is a pointer to the calling function (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee). So `arguments.callee` is the original function of the same instantiated function (now object).

ECMAScript 2015 introduced the `Function.name` attribute (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) which is supported by Chrome, Opera, Firefox and Safari but not in Internet Explorer (in my IE11 it is `undefined`), so accessing the instantiated function's name through `arguments.callee.name` works in all browsers, except IE.

However, there is a small trick to get the name from inside of instantiated functions (then objects) in all browsers by creating a helper method to the `Function.prototype` attribute (so it gets inherited to all functions) and then extract the function name from the already available `toString()` method:

```
Function.prototype.getName = function()
{
    var funcName = this.toString().substr(9);
    return funcName.substr(0, funcName.indexOf('(')).trim();
};

function MyException(message) {
    this.message = message;
    this.name = arguments.callee.getName();  // Get orig. function name
    this.toString = function() {
        return this.name + ': ' + this.message;
    };
}

try {
    throw new MyException('Hello world');
}
catch (e) {
    alert(e);  // "MyException: Hello world"
}
```

Note 1: Anonymous function are not supported, because they have no name. But a named function can be used:

```
var MyException = function MyException(message) {
    // ...
}
```

Note 2: `arguments.callee` is not available in ES5 strict mode.

Note 3: I used `trim` method of `String.prototype.trim()`, which is available in IE9+. Create a shim if not available:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim)
{
    String.prototype.trim = function() { return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); };
}
```

Comment: This works for `function F(){ console.log('F'); }` but not for `var F = function (){ console.log('F'); }`

Comment: Because in your example you create an anonymous function which has no name. You can use named functions like this: `var F = function F(){console.log('F'); }`. But thanks for your note, I have added this to the answer.

Comment: Note that in some (hopefully old and no longer used) [*versions of IE*](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs), named function expressions created a variable in the enclosing scope (often global) that referenced the function.

Answer (score 0):

Access [Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) property, pay attention to list of supported browsers, if it suits to you that's great)

```
function MyException(message) {
    this.message = message;
    this.name = MyException.name;  // 'MyException'
    this.toString = function() {
        return this.name + ': ' + this.message;
    };
}
```

Comment: `Function.name` is undefined in IE. And I didn't want to write the functions name again inside it (otherwise I could use the string version from my example in the question).